# Value initialization: MSVC vs clang

Tags: c++, visual-studio, initialization, clang, language-lawyer

```
#include<cstddef>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct A {
    T m_a[N];
    A() : m_a{} {}
};

struct S {
    explicit S(int i=4) {}
};

int main() {
    A<S, 3> an;
}
```

The above code compiles fine with MSVC (2017), but fails with clang 3.8.0 (Output of `clang++ --version && clang++ -std=c++14 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp`):

```
clang version 3.8.0 (tags/RELEASE_380/final 263969)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin
main.cpp:6:15: error: chosen constructor is explicit in copy-initialization
    A() : m_a{} {}
              ^
main.cpp:14:13: note: in instantiation of member function 'A<S, 3>::A' requested here
    A<S, 3> an;
            ^
main.cpp:10:14: note: constructor declared here
    explicit S(int i=4) {}
             ^
main.cpp:6:15: note: in implicit initialization of array element 0 with omitted initializer
    A() : m_a{} {}
              ^
1 error generated.
```

clang 5.0 also refuses to compile this:

```
<source>:6:17: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
    A() : m_a{} {}
                ^
<source>:6:14: error: expected '('
    A() : m_a{} {}
             ^
2 errors generated.
```

If I use simple parentheses in `A`s constructor to (i.e. `A() : m_a() {}`), it compiles fine. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) I would have suspected that both should result in the same (i.e. value initialization). Am I missing something or is this a bug in one of the compilers?

Comment: Note [gcc produces warnings but it builds](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1B5xDJ0VrvuaxmYv)

Comment: Clang 3.8.0 is fairly old. Have you tried with a modern clang (like 5.0.1)?

Comment: @JesperJuhl It doesn't compile on clang trunk :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `m_a{}`:

- [[dcl.init]/17.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#17.1) sends us to [[dcl.init.list]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list), and [[dcl.init.list]/3.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list#3.4) says that we perform aggregate initialization on `m_a` per [[dcl.init.aggr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.aggr).

  > The semantics of initializers are as follows. [...]
  >
  > - If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) *braced-init-list* or is `=` *braced-init-list*, the object or reference is list-initialized.
  > - [...]
  >
  > ---
  >
  > List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
  >
  > - [...]
  > - Otherwise, if `T` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed.
  > - [...]
- [[dcl.init.aggr]/5.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.aggr#5.2) says that we copy-initialize each element of `m_a` from an empty initializer list, i.e., `{}`.

  > For a non-union aggregate, each element that is not an explicitly initialized element is initialized as follows:
  >
  > - [...]
  > - Otherwise, if the element is not a reference, the element is copy-initialized from an empty initializer list ([dcl.init.list]).
  > - [...]
- This sends us back to [[dcl.init]/17.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#17.1) for the initialization of each element, which again sends us to [[dcl.init.list]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list).
- This time we hit [[dcl.init.list]/3.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list#3.5), which says that the element is value-initialized.

  > List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
  >
  > - [...]
  > - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements and `T` is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized.
  > - [...]
- Which brings us to [[dcl.init]/8.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#8.1), which says that the element is default-initialized.

  > To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
  >
  > - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type with either no default constructor ([class.ctor]) or a default constructor that is user-provided or deleted, then the object is default-initialized;
  > - [...]
- Which hits [[dcl.init]/7.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#7.1), which says we enumerate constructors per [[over.match.ctor]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.ctor) and perform overload resolution on the initializer `()`;

  > To *default-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
  >
  > - If `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated
  >     ([over.match.ctor]), and the best one for the *initializer* `()` is
  >     chosen through overload resolution. The constructor thus selected is
  >     called, with an empty argument list, to initialize the object.
  > - [...]
- and [over.match.ctor] says:

  > For direct-initialization **or default-initialization that is not in the
  >   context of copy-initialization**, the candidate functions are all the
  >   constructors of the class of the object being initialized. For
  >   copy-initialization, the candidate functions are all the converting
  >   constructors of that class.
- This default-initialization *is* in the context of copy-initialization, so the candidate functions are "all the converting constructors of that class".
- The explicit default constructor is not a converting constructor. As a result, there is no viable constructor. Hence overload resolution fails, and the program is ill-formed.

For `m_a()`:

- We hit [[dcl.init]/17.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#17.4), which says that the array is value-initialized.

  > The semantics of initializers are as follows. [...]
  >
  > - [...]
  > - If the initializer is `()`, the object is value-initialized.
  > - [...]
- Which brings us to [[dcl.init]/8.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#8.3), which says that each element is value-initialized.

  > To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
  >
  > - [...]
  > - if `T` is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
  > - [...]
- Which again brings us to [[dcl.init]/8.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#8.1), and then to [[dcl.init]/7.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#7.1), and so we again enumerate constructors per [[over.match.ctor]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.ctor) and perform overload resolution on the initializer `()`;
- This time, the default-initialization *is not* in the context of copy-initialization, so the candidate functions are "all the constructors of the class of the object being initialized".
- This time, the explicit default constructor *is* a candidate and selected by overload resolution. So the program is well-formed.

Answer (score 10):

Clang is correct.

Your confusion comes from:

> From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) I would have suspected that both should result in the same (i.e. value initialization).

No they have different effects. Note the notes in that page:

> In all cases, if the empty pair of braces {} is used and T is an aggregate type, aggregate-initialization is performed instead of value-initialization.

That means when initialized with braced-init-list, for aggregate type, aggregate-initialization is preferred to be performed. With `A() : m_a{} {}`, and `m_a` is an array, which belongs to [aggregate type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Explanation), then [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) is performed instead:

(emphasis mine)

> Each `direct public base, (since C++17)` array element, or non-static class member, in order of array subscript/appearance in the class definition, is **copy-initialized** from the corresponding clause of the initializer list.

and

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members `and bases (since C++17)` or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members `and bases (since C++17)` are initialized `by their default initializers, if provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14)` by empty lists, in accordance with the usual list-initialization rules (which performs value-initialization for non-class types and non-aggregate classes with default constructors, and aggregate initialization for aggregates).

That means, the remaining elements, i.e. all the 3 elements of `m_a` will be copy-initialized from the empty list; for empty list the default constructor of `S` will be considered but it's declared as `explicit`; the [copy-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) won't invoke `explicit` constructors:

> copy-list-initialization (both explicit and non-explicit constructors are considered, but only non-explicit constructors may be called)

---

On the other hand, `A() : m_a() {}` performs [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), then

> 3) if T is an array type, each element of the array is value-initialized;

then

> 1) if T is a class type with no default constructor or with a user-provided or deleted default constructor, the object is default-initialized;

then the default constructor of `S` is invoked to initialize the elements of `m_a`. Whether it's `explicit` or not doesn't matter for [default initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).

Comment: FWIW the relevant standard section is [over.match.list]/1

Answer (score 2):

This is explicitly ill-formed by the Standard (the question is, though, why?):

`m_a{}` list-initializes the `S::m_a`:

> #### [`[dcl.init.list]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#list-1)
>
> *List-initialization* is initialization of an object or reference from a *braced-init-list*.
>   Such an initializer is called an initializer list, and the comma-separated *initializer-clauses* of the *initializer-list* or *designated-initializer-clauses* of the *designated-initializer-list* are called the elements of the initializer list. An initializer list may be empty. List-initialization can occur in *direct-initialization* or *copy-initialization* contexts; *list-initialization* in a *direct-initialization* context is called *direct-list-initialization* and *list-initialization* in a *copy-initialization* context is called *copy-list-initialization*.

As an array, `A<S, 3>::m_a` is an aggregate type ([`[dcl.init.aggr]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr)).

> #### [`[dcl.init.aggr]/3.3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#3.3)
>
> 3. When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list as specified in [dcl.init.list], [...]
>      3.3 the initializer list must be `{}`, and there are no explicitly initialized elements.

following, since *there are no explicitly initialized elements*:

> #### [`[dcl.init.aggr]/5.2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#5.2)
>
> 5. For a non-union aggregate, each element that is not an explicitly initialized element is initialized as follows: [...]
>      5.2 if the element is not a reference, the element is *copy-initialized* from an empty initializer list (`[dcl.init.list]`).

Each `S` of `A<S, 3>::m_a` is, then, *copy-initialized*:

> #### [`[dcl.init]/17.6.3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.3)
>
> 17. The semantics of initializers are as follows.
>       The *destination type* is the type of the object or reference being initialized and the *source type* is the type of the initializer expression.
>       If the initializer is not a single (possibly parenthesized) expression, the source type is not defined. [...]
>       17.6 If the destination type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type: [...]
>       17.6.3 Otherwise (i.e., for the remaining *copy-initialization* cases), user-defined **conversion sequences that can convert** from the source type to the destination type or (when a conversion function is used) to a derived class thereof are enumerated as described in [over.match.copy], and the best one is chosen through overload resolution.
>       **If the conversion cannot be done or is ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed.**

Since the default constructor of `S` is explicit, it *cannot convert from the source type to the destination type* (`S`).

The syntax using `m_a()` is, on the other hand, not *aggregate member initialization* and does not invoke *copy-initialization*.

Comment: Wrong quotes. Aggregate initialization copy-initializes the omitted elements from `{}` and so uses the list-initialization rules.

Comment: @T.C. Yes, _list-initialize_ the **array**, `[dcl.init]/17.6.3` is about the class type ("_destination type_", `S` here). Am I wrong?

Comment: @YSC ["*If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) braced-init-list or is = braced-init-list, the object or reference is list-initialized.*"](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.1) I think

Comment: @T.C. fixed. I took in consideration your remark. This is better I think.

Comment: Still wrong. You never hit [dcl.init]/17.6.3. (What would be the "source type" of an empty initializer list?)

Comment: @T.C. _" If the initializer is not a single (possibly parenthesized) expression, the source type is not defined."_

Comment: So what's the ICS you are looking for, then?

Comment: @T.C. maybe you can help me see better. What does _" if the element is not a reference, the element is copy-initialized from an empty initializer list "_ (`[dcl.init.aggr]/5.2`) mean then?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the standard correctly clang is correct.

According to [dcl.init.aggr]/8.5.1:2

> When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list, as specified
>   in 8.5.4, the elements of the initializer list are taken as
>   initializers for the members of the aggregate, in increasing subscript
>   or member order. Each member is copy-initialized from the
>   corresponding initializer-clause.

And further down in the same clause [dcl.init.aggr]/8.5.1:7

> If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are
>   members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized
>   shall be initialized from its brace-or-equal-initializer or, if there
>   is no brace-or-equal- initializer, from an empty initializer list

According to the rules for list initialization [over.match.list]/13.3.1.7

> In copy-list-initialization, if an explicit constructor is chosen, the
>   initialization is ill-formed.